# Помогите получить ссылку на поток аудио вк

Tags: php, вконтакте, аудио

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста получить ссылку на аудио!
апи закрыто, как я понял, вк шифрует ссылки..

Comment: Судя по [новости](https://vc.ru/18185-vk-music-api) закрыт только доступ к аудиозаписям, защищёнными правами. [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/57993/) приведён пример класса, не уверен, насколько актуальный.

Comment: Новости же были на этой неделе: ограничение 1 час в день бесплатного прослушивания, с последующим уменьшением до 30 минут и введение платы за любое прослушивание. Плюньте на этот вконтактик, займитесь чем-нибудь другим.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский не актуально к сожалению(